# Does FindDistributionParameters have any inbuilt parameter error estimation available?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions

`FindDistributionParameters` is super useful for extracting parameters and using them for other things, like defining random variables.

However I can't find any literature on how to extract the errors in the parameters that `FindDistributionParameters` determines.

For example:

```
TestData = RandomVariate[RayleighDistributiom[1.2234],10000]
FindDistributionParameters[TestData, RayleighDistribution[\[Sigma]], ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"]
```

Now obviously I can just run this $N$ times to get an idea on the error. Or if I have real data where I only have one set, I can bootstrap it and again run $N$ times. But I'd like to know if there is an inbuilt estimation on the parameter errors already?

Comment: Have you already seen `DistributionFitTest[]`?

Comment: Depends on how loose you want to be in the definition of "inbuilt".  One can use the result from the `LogLikelihood` function to obtain estimates of the standard errors of the parameters (along with the estimated covariances).

Comment: @J.M. I thought this tests only for normally distributed data? Would you be willing to throw together a quick example?

Comment: @JimB Any method that just uses the initial set of data would be good! I would just prefer to avoid bootstrapping data.

Comment: "I thought this tests only for normally distributed data?" - did you *look* at e.g. the second example under "Basic Examples" in the help file for `DistributionFitTest[]`, where one is testing for a fit with the Pareto distribution? How about the third and succeeding examples under "Scope"?

Comment: @J.M. Point taken, but doesn't this just provide a measure of how well the data represents a certain distribution. I don't see how this can be used to provide error estimates on individual distribution parameters. But this is a very useful function nonetheless so thanks for directing me to it.

Comment: I would avoid testing hypotheses about goodness-of-fit in that with enough data you will reject whatever distribution you are testing.  Also, such tests have decided for you (without any subject matter knowledge) what features of the fit are most important (again, no matter what the objective is).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm glad to see you are wanting to obtain estimates of precision (rather than hypothesis testing):  "An estimate of a parameter without an associated measure of precision is at best of unknown value."  Of course, getting an estimate of standard error or a precise estimate of a parameter doesn't help if the distribution is inappropriate for the data.

The necessary calculations are already performed internally to obtain the maximum likelihood estimate so I don't know why `FindDistributionParameters` or some other builtin function doesn't offer that.  Fortunately the calculations are relatively simple (especially for a one-parameter distribution).

Here's an example that matches your example:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
TestData = RandomVariate[RayleighDistribution[1.2234], 10000];
mle = FindDistributionParameters[TestData, RayleighDistribution[σ],
  ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"]
(* {σ -> 1.21208} *)

logL = LogLikelihood[RayleighDistribution[σ], TestData];
se = Sqrt[-1/(D[logL, {σ, 2}]) /. mle]
(* 0.0060604 *)
```

When there are multiple parameters, an `Inverse` is necessary which results in an estimated covariance matrix.  Here's an example for a 2-parameter Weibull:

```
(* Generate data from a 2-parameter Weibull *)
SeedRandom[12345];
TestData = RandomVariate[WeibullDistribution[1.2345, 5.4321, 10.9876], 10000];

(* Find maximum likelihood estimates *)
mle = FindDistributionParameters[TestData, WeibullDistribution[α, β, 10.9876],
  ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"]
(* {α -> 1.24141, β -> 5.36107} *) 

(* Get the log of the likelihood *)
logL = LogLikelihood[WeibullDistribution[α, β, 10.9876], TestData];

(* Find the hessian evaluated at the maximum likelihood solution *)
hessian = (D[logL, {{α, β}, 2}]) /. mle;

(* Get estimate of covariance matrix *)
(cov = -Inverse[hessian]) // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0.000093733 & 0.000137995 \\
 0.000137995 & 0.00206814 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

```
(* Standard errors *)
seα = cov[[1, 1]]^0.5
(* 0.00968158 *)
seβ = cov[[2, 2]]^0.5
(* 0.0454768 *)
```

Comment: You're a bloody marvel. Can I ask what the meaning of `se = Sqrt[-1/(D[logL, {σ, 2}]) /. mle]` is? As in why is the equation of that form, does it have a name so I can read up about it?

Comment: `se` represents the estimate of the standard error associated with the parameter estimate.  The reciprocal of minus the second derivative of the log of the likelihood  evaluated at the maximum likelihood estimate of $\sigma$ obtains the estimate of the variance.  To get the standard error one takes the square root of that.  However, I suspect you want a general description of the procedure.  I'll look for a concise blurb on that.

Comment: superb. I shall accept your answer!

Comment: final question, is the procedure any different for distributions with more than one parameter? I ask as I adapted the code for a three parameter distribution and the derivative hasn't yet compiled: `TestData = 
  RandomVariate[WeibullDistribution[1.2345, 5.4321, 10.9876], 10000];
mle = FindDistributionParameters[TestData, 
  WeibullDistribution[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]], 
  ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"]
logL = LogLikelihood[WeibullDistribution[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]],
    TestData];
se = Sqrt[-1/(D[logL, {\[Alpha], 2}, {\[Beta], 2}, {\[Gamma], 2}])]`

Comment: You've pick an example where no maximum likelihood estimate exists when all 3 of the Weibull parameters are unknown.  I'll put in a 2-parameter Weibull example.

Comment: Continuation about the 3-parameter Weibull when all 3 parameters are unknown.  As the estimate of $\gamma$ gets closer to the smallest data value, the log likelihood keeps on increasing with the estimates of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ constantly changing.  And when the estimate of $\gamma$ is set to the smallest data value, the log likelihood is $-\infty$. Hence, the maximum likelihood estimators don't exist.  So in this case why does `FindDistributionParameters` give you a maximum likelihood solution?  Got me.

Comment: Huh. Interesting. I've tested `FindDistributionParameters` with Weibull distributions extensively. Given enough statistics it always returns the correct initial values of $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ that I give it. If I fix the one of the parameters for example $\alpha$, run your SE code on the remaining two. Then do a second stage were I fix another, say, $\beta$, and determine errors in the same way. Could that be valid?

Comment: This issue of no maximum likelihood solution always occurs but only sometimes shows up in most software as a problem when $\alpha<1$.  Here's a link that describes the issue: https://www.weibull.com/hotwire/issue148/hottopics148.htm.  Note that the *Mathematica* parameter $\alpha$ corresponds to $\beta$ in the link.  So the fact that it "generally seems to work" might be because `FindDistributionParameters` tends to settle on a local maximum rather than the global maximum.  Maximum likelihood can have schizophrenic issues.

Comment: That's really, really interesting. Thanks for this answer, you've provided a lot of information.